# Can load the public key in java using X509EncodedKeySpec but unable to parse it with openssl

Tags: java, openssl, public-key

I have a private/public key pair that was generated by someone else and handed down to me. The pair is currently used in active deployment. Both keys are stored in files with a .der extension.
The private key I can verify and parse allright:

> openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -nocrypt -in private_key.der

Public one however fails with:

> Error decrypting key 139834801850032:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1338:
>   139834801850032:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:852:
>   139834801850032:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding
>   routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1
>   error:tasn_dec.c:772:Field=version, Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO

The public key is currently used by a java application and loaded as follows:

```
     byte[] publicKeyArray - <the public key bytes straight from file>
     X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyArray);
     KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

     java.security.PublicKey publicKey = factory.generatePublic(spec);
```

The class documentation for X509EncodedKeySpec reads:

```
 * This class represents the ASN.1 encoding of a public key,
 * encoded according to the ASN.1 type {@code SubjectPublicKeyInfo}.
 * The {@code SubjectPublicKeyInfo} syntax is defined in the X.509
 * standard as follows:
 *
 * <pre>
 * SubjectPublicKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
 *   algorithm AlgorithmIdentifier,
 *   subjectPublicKey BIT STRING }
 * </pre>
```

and:

```
   * Creates a new X509EncodedKeySpec with the given encoded key.
     *
     * @param encodedKey the key, which is assumed to be
     * encoded according to the X.509 standard. The contents of the
     * array are copied to protect against subsequent modification.
     * @exception NullPointerException if {@code encodedKey}
     * is null.
     */
```

I've tried experimenting with different openssl commands including asn1parse but no luck. How can I use/extract the public key from my file using something other than the java X509EncodedKeySpec?

Comment: I am wondering this myself. If you already have a solution It would be great if you could share it. If not, I'm happy to try to help come up with a solution.